# Discord.js - How to delete a defined event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to delete a event like this code:

```
let event = bot.on("voiceStateUpdate",async (oldMember, newMember) => {console.info("event happened")});

event.delete(); //Function I want.
```

When I join a voice channel, deleted event musn't run.

I can disable events with if statement but my bot makes new event when I run a custom command, so it slows the events.

My english isn't very well. I tried to translate as much as I could.

Answer (score 0):

Discord.js event is always run in background even if you don't define in your code. So if you want to avoid useless event I suggest you to using discord.js-light
https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js-light

Comment: Thanks but I don't want use discord.js-light.

Comment: So you have to fork and modify discord.js code core if you want to do it

Comment: Forgot to tell you that if you only need event fire one times only there is something like `bot.once("voiceStateUpdate", ...)`